# Django and python 2.7 from ports on Mac OS X

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7, macports

I have Django 1.4.1 and Python 2.7 installed from ports on Mac OS X 10.7. When I try to run manage.py runserver 8000, I'm getting an error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x10bb840d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/rankor777/PycharmProjects/PyCart/PyCartApp/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Photo(models.Model):
  File "/Users/rankor777/PycharmProjects/PyCart/PyCartApp/models.py", line 41, in Photo
    title = models.Model(max_length=128)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 289, in __init__
    if args_len > len(self._meta.fields):
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

What's this, and how to fix it?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to install python or django via MacPorts. Use easy_install (or pip) in a virtualenv with the system-installed Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you think this has something to do with MacPorts. The traceback shows the error, which is in line 41 of `PyCartApp/models.py`: you've put `models.Model(max_length=128)` where I presume you meant to put `models.CharField(max_length=128)`.

Comment: Oh, of course, stupid mistake. Need to sleep a little bit more :)